# Leaner mixt effect model

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

Is it possible to have more than one model and each work with different acoustic correlates? I mean if i have for example measure 1 and measure 2 and i tried to test them across a couple of models and i found out that measure 1 works with model structure "A" and measure 2 works with model structure "B"

do i have to state that in my paper that I have two models, one for measure 1 and one for measure 2?   an how can i tell where the significance is after looking at the bottom window in the R?

Comment: Obviously you have to describe all the  models and measures used in your paper. R can be used in a text console without windows or can be used with one or more windows. In the latter case you are free to choose, which window you put a the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but anyway this is off topic for SO. I think you'll find the appropriate audience on stats.stackexchange.com. You'll also want to provide more specific details about the problem so that others can understand and help you better.